# QGIS 2.14 open raster crash

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-2.14

I am using QGIS 2.14 on Mac OS X 10.11.3; every time I try to open a raster file, in any format, QGIS crash, any suggestions?

Comment: Please report QGIS bugs/issues here https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/issues with log file of crash to help debug

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a bug report rather than a question on StackExchange.